# What are the uses of JDK inside the oracle database client installed location?

Tags: java, oracle

I observed today that there is a JDK inside the Oracle database client/server installed location in linux box.

I know the jre is used in using netca(GUI) other assistive GUI tools, but can someone explain what are the uses of this JRE then this?

I am not trying to remove or overwrite this JDK but i don`t seem to find any explanation anywhere about this lower version JDK then current released at that time of release particular ORACLE database client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full client includes an old version of SQL Developer, which requires a JDK.

The 11gR1 client includes SQL Developer 1.1.3 and JDK 1.5.0_11; the 11gR2 server (and as far as I know standalone client) includes [SQL Developer 1.5.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index-archive154-087346.html) with and JDK 1.5.0_30. At least on Linux. Oracle 12c includes SQL Devloper 3.2 I believe, so presumably includes JDK 6.

They supply the old version of SQL Developer, so they also supply a matching, compatible version of the JDK, even if Java had moved on since that version of SQL Developer.

The current version, [SQL Developer 4.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), [requires JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sqldev-relnotes-41-2372786.html).

There may be other uses for the older JDK for other tools, but that's an obvious one.

Comment: I will also add that they use the same JDK version on all platforms. So even if they are "no" problems with JDK8 on Windows, some newer JDKs might Segfault on Linux/AIX when displaying old AWT based GUI tools.